# Cadastral areas of Ukraine

Tags: data, ukraine

I´m looking for cadastral areas of villages of Ukraine. Is there some available that can be used to work with them in Qgis?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! If you are looking for open data then opendata.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask

Comment: This question should be asked in the https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

https://zemlevporyadnik.com.ua/ru/publichnaya-kadastrovaya-karta.html

Quote (translated):

> Due to the introduction of martial law in Ukraine, the public
> cadastral map has been disabled. There are no plans to resume the work
> of the public cadastral map until the end of martial law. You can read
> about what options are now available to work with the cadastre on this
> page below.